# How to access the integer returned from SQL Count

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Going to make this quick. 
So I am doing something that should be relatively simple but none of the answers I have found online (Yes, I have read through and implemented them ALL) have yielded the right result.

Basically, all I am trying to do is count how many times a specific field shows up in a column in one of my databases. Sounds easy, right?

Well, this is where it gets a bit sketchy for me. The query I am trying to use to attain this information is this:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT user_id COUNT(*) FROM ch_documents_list WHERE user_id = $users_id ";
```

From here, I want to take the result as an `int` and `echo` it into a specific part of the site (not important as to where exactly).

The only way I can get information out of the result is to run a `print_r($result)` Where `$result` is set to the response of the query.

**NOTE** The information printed looks like this:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 5 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

Which, as many of you can figure out, is useless. What changes do I need to make in order to get this right?

Thanks everyone!

**Pasting more of my code below**

Query As Of Now

```
  $dbname_classes = "classes";
  $conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname_classes);
  $sql2 = "SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS total FROM ch_documents_list WHERE user_id = $users_id";
  $result2 = $conn->query($sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
```

Then below in the `html`

```
<div class='overview-stat'><?php  echo $row['total']; ?></div>
```

Which leads to this:
`Notice: Undefined index: total`

Comment: you can use CAST() method of mysql

Comment: You are not meant to get that value from the result object you get as a handle. You are meant to use that handle to fetch the rows of the result set which also contain those count values. That is shown in about 558254893254845 different answers on SO. You claim you have implemented them all? Well, looks like you did not really pay attention then...

Comment: Apart from that: your sql query contains a syntax error, you have to add a comma between `user_id` and `COUNT(*)`, or you have to use `COUNT(user_id)`. _And_ you need to somehow _group_ your result (`GROUP BY`), otherwise the query does not make any sense. That is clearly shown in the documentation, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM ch_documents_list WHERE user_id = $users_id ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query );
$rows   = mysqli_num_rows($result);
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: Tried this many times, no luck

Comment: Okay i am trying for another way. But its working for me fine.

Comment: I got it by using a mixture of everything, but yours helped the most. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @Ethan.. is this code has resolved the problem?

Comment: @Ethan this answer is just terrible. never do it this way

Comment: @YourCommonSense how do you suggest I do this then?

Answer (score 2):

May this be helpful.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT  COUNT(*) as total FROM ch_documents_list WHERE user_id = $users_id";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql2); // $con is Boolean returned from mysqli_connect()
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["total"];
```

Comment: Sorry, this returns the long array that I do not need. I only need a count of how many times `user_id` appears in the table in `integer` form

Answer (score 1):

Using the SQL `AS` Keyword

Rewrite your query like this below query:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS total FROM ch_documents_list WHERE user_id = $users_id";
```

After that just index your result array using the total key and boom you got your int counts

Like: `$result['total']`

Comment: `Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array` was returned

Comment: You have to Fetch your result as an array using mysqli_fetch_array()

Comment: If object is returned Fetch your result using `$result->total;`

Comment: `Undefined index: total` when trying to do `$needed = $row['total'];` after `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: Try using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` for result fetching then Fetch the total using $row['total']

Comment: No matter what I do it says that `total` is undefined

Comment: Your query should look like this: `$sql2 = "SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS total FROM ch_documents_list WHERE user_id = $users_id";`

Answer (score 1):

May not the propper way, but works fine for me since years:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT user_id COUNT(*) AS total FROM ch_documents_list WHERE user_id = $users_id";
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)
```

You can then access it with

```
 $result['total']
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '$needed'` after trying to grab integer by using `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)` and queries mentioned above

Comment: Can you post more of your Code? I do it this way since years and never had problems with it...

Comment: Oh damn my bad sorry. Too early in the morning. Try it this way:

$sql = "SELECT user_id COUNT(*) AS total FROM ch_documents_list WHERE user_id = $users_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0];

Comment: `Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean` Any ideas?

Comment: Please make sure your SQL Query is correct. Maybe a typo or something... ?

Comment: Can't comment on the other posts (not enough reputation) BUT i just want you to say that with the solution of Rana (which one worked for you) you always fetch all data from mysql... This will slow your application unnecessary. So i hope you have this COUNT in your SQL statement...

Answer (score -2):

return int two query example:

```
1. $sql2 = "SELECT  COUNT(user_id) as id FROM ch_documents_list WHERE user_id = $users_id";
```

**You should return count

> mysql_num_rows

**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "databasename");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_id FROM ch_documents_list WHERE user_id = $users_id");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
```

> this is mysqli function support

Comment: the first example would always be 1
the second one you returned all the data not just their numbers which is very bad if he only need the number

Comment: Sorry, always returns as `1`

Comment: first return 1 array id in all rows count. and second example where in  pass user id and match only one so return always 1.